# Slow script task when normalizing data for insert into SQL

Tags: ssis

We've got about 50 million JSON-serialized strings that get inserted into SQL in roughly the following procedure:

- 1) Read all entries in a source table that haven't been processed
- 2) Deserialize each into a C# object
- 3) Validate against SQL the row is unique by device ID and timestamp - discard if not unique (theres about 1 duplicate per 2000 rows). There can be duplicates in the source data or in the production tables and I need to validate against both.
- 4) Check if a child object exists and if not, insert and return inserted row ID, otherwise just return the row ID of the child object.
- 5) Repeat step 4 for about 10 multi-level nested subclasses, then link in subclass the primary key of the parent class.
- 6) Update the original row to set an "Inserted" column to true.

The whole lot is done in a single SSIS Script task and has been working well for a long time.

For step 4 and 5 above, each source row instantiates a new SqlCommand and .ExecuteScalar() to retrieve the inserted row ID for use in subsequent inserts/updates of that object.

Everything works well row by row but we need to re-import all source data into some new databases and the speed is very slow, only a few hundred rows per second. It's obvious the large number of individual reads, inserts and updates are slow, also the overhead of ADO.

I am at a loss how to improve the speed because many functions require blocking to guarantee uniqueness.

If I do an SSIS Data Flow task with fast load, it won't guarantee uniqueness during the transform.

Would it be prudent to split say, 500 source rows at a time into 10 threads after validating uniqueness then run the monolithic insert process?

Are there better conceptual ways to achieve the same result?

Comment: Script task is not the most performant way of doing trasformations in SSIS. If you are using SQL Server older than 2016 (or any other database engine which does not support JSON), I would keep only JSON deserialization inside the script task, insert the results into a stage table and carry on from there using either SSIS transformations or pure T-SQL. This is a lot of development though.

Comment: I think I've got a better workaround. Rather than validating the data before insert, I hit it with a big hammer by relying on SQL throwing a uniqueness error. I've changed my OLEDB Destination to a maximum insert commit size of 200 rows and redirecting error output to another OLEDB Destination with a maximum insert commit size of 1. This way nothing is blocking and I'm getting about 2,000 inserts a second. A little more optimization and I might improve it further.